# JFreechart: Displaying X axis with values after specific units

Tags: jfreechart

I am using jfreechart for displaying line graph.Now, on X axis it shows value for every (x,y) pair on chart.As a result the X axis has huge amount of values getting overlapped.I want to display few values eg after every 5 units or something like that.How is this possible using Jfreechart.

Comment: Please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits the problem and shows what you've tried.

Answer (score 3):

Before the `NumberAxis` of the chart's plot is drawn, its tick marks are refreshed. The result is a `List` that includes a `NumberTick` object for each tick mark of the axis.

By overriding the function `NumberAxis.refreshTicks` you can control how and if the marks will be shown.

For example, in the following code I get all tick marks and iterate through them looking for `TickType.MAJOR`. If the value of a major tick mark is not dividable by 5, it gets replaced by a minor tick mark.

As a result, only values dividable by 5 will be shown with their text label.

```
XYPlot plot = (XYPlot) chart.getPlot();

NumberAxis myAxis = new NumberAxis(plot.getDomainAxis().getLabel()) {
  @Override
  public List refreshTicks(Graphics2D g2, AxisState state,
                           Rectangle2D dataArea, RectangleEdge edge) {

    List allTicks = super.refreshTicks(g2, state, dataArea, edge);
    List myTicks = new ArrayList();

    for (Object tick : allTicks) {
      NumberTick numberTick = (NumberTick) tick;

      if (TickType.MAJOR.equals(numberTick.getTickType()) &&
                    (numberTick.getValue() % 5 != 0)) {
        myTicks.add(new NumberTick(TickType.MINOR, numberTick.getValue(), "",
                    numberTick.getTextAnchor(), numberTick.getRotationAnchor(),
                    numberTick.getAngle()));
        continue;
      }
      myTicks.add(tick);
    }
    return myTicks;
  }
};

plot.setDomainAxis(myAxis);
```