# Hide axis label jfreechart

Tags: java, charts, hide, jfreechart, linechart

I generate this chart with Jfreechart lib

I would like to hide the labels in axis, but show only the first and the last value, How I can do?

Thank soo much!!

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to override NumberAxis.refreshTicks method (If you are using line chart). A bit similar example is available here :

[JFreechart: Displaying X axis with values after specific units](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10753961/jfreechart-displaying-x-axis-with-values-after-specific-units)

When you would set only two tick values by using this function other values would be automatically gets invisible.