# Custom label for ValueAxis, JFreeChart

Tags: jfreechart

I am having labels after my bars(not displayed here) which result in a longer range of values then wanted(i.e. would like to remove "125" in this case).
How can I remove the last value in my ValueAxis/RangeAxis(NumberAxis?)?

[image]

First thought I could just remove the highest value with Overriding the `refreshTicks()` method like this: [JFreechart: Displaying X axis with values after specific units](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10753961/jfreechart-displaying-x-axis-with-values-after-specific-units)

But I lost the empty space with that one. Then I thought I could Override the "drawTickMarksAndLabels" method:

```
ValueAxis axis = new ValueAxis(plot.getDomainAxis().getLabel(),
                null) {

    @Override
    protected AxisState drawTickMarksAndLabels(Graphics2D g2,
        double cursor, Rectangle2D plotArea,
        Rectangle2D dataArea, RectangleEdge edge) {

// changes
}
plot.setRangeAxis(axis);
```

The problem with this one is that I get `NullpointerException` when not specifying `TickUnitSource`. Any idea how I can give a correct `TickUnitSource` to a custom `ValueAxis`?

Source code:

```
public class BarChartDemo extends ApplicationFrame {

    /**
     * Creates a new demo instance.
     *
     * @param title  the frame title.
     */
    public BarChartDemo(final String title) {
        super(title);
        final CategoryDataset dataset = createDataset();
        final JFreeChart chart = createChart(dataset);
        final ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);
        chartPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 270));
        setContentPane(chartPanel);
    }

    /**
     * Returns a sample dataset.
     * 
     * @return The dataset.
     */
    private CategoryDataset createDataset() {

        // row keys...
        final String series1 = "First";

        // column keys...
        final String category1 = "Category 1";
        final String category2 = "Category 2";
        final String category3 = "Category 3";

        // create the dataset...
        final DefaultCategoryDataset dataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset();

        dataset.addValue(70.0, series1, category1);
        dataset.addValue(40.0, series1, category2);
        dataset.addValue(100.0, series1, category3);



        return dataset;
    }

    /**
     * Creates a sample chart.
     * 
     * @param dataset  the dataset.
     * 
     * @return The chart.
     */
    private JFreeChart createChart(final CategoryDataset dataset) {

        // create the chart...
        final JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createBarChart(
            "Bar Chart Demo",         // chart title
            "Category",               // domain axis label
            "%",                  // range axis label
            dataset,                  // data
            PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, // orientation
            false,                     // include legend
            false,                     // tooltips?
            false                     // URLs?
        );

        CategoryPlot plot = chart.getCategoryPlot();

        final int maxPercent = 100;

        // Adding some extra space
        NumberAxis rangeAxis = (NumberAxis)plot.getRangeAxis();
        rangeAxis.setRange(0, maxPercent+(maxPercent*0.4));

//        ValueAxis axis = new ValueAxis(plot.getRangeAxis().getLabel(),
//              null) {
//
//          @Override
//          protected AxisState drawTickMarksAndLabels(Graphics2D g2,
//                  double cursor, Rectangle2D plotArea,
//                  Rectangle2D dataArea, RectangleEdge edge) {
//
//              AxisState state = new AxisState(cursor);
//
//              if (isAxisLineVisible()) {
//                  drawAxisLine(g2, cursor, dataArea, edge);
//              }
//
//              double ol = getTickMarkOutsideLength();
//              double il = getTickMarkInsideLength();
//
//              List ticks = refreshTicks(g2, state, dataArea, edge);
//              state.setTicks(ticks);
//              g2.setFont(getTickLabelFont());
//              Iterator iterator = ticks.iterator();
//              while (iterator.hasNext()) {
//                  ValueTick tick = (ValueTick) iterator.next();
//                  if (isTickLabelsVisible()) {
//                      g2.setPaint(getTickLabelPaint());
//                      float[] anchorPoint = calculateAnchorPoint(
//                              tick, cursor, dataArea, edge);
//                      
//                      System.out.println(tick.getText());
//                      
//                      TextUtilities.drawRotatedString(tick.getText(),
//                              g2, anchorPoint[0], anchorPoint[1],
//                              tick.getTextAnchor(), tick.getAngle(),
//                              tick.getRotationAnchor());
//                  }
//
//                  if (isTickMarksVisible()) {
//                      float xx = (float) valueToJava2D(
//                              tick.getValue(), dataArea, edge);
//                      Line2D mark = null;
//                      g2.setStroke(getTickMarkStroke());
//                      g2.setPaint(getTickMarkPaint());
//                      if (edge == RectangleEdge.LEFT) {
//                          mark = new Line2D.Double(cursor - ol, xx,
//                                  cursor + il, xx);
//                      } else if (edge == RectangleEdge.RIGHT) {
//                          mark = new Line2D.Double(cursor + ol, xx,
//                                  cursor - il, xx);
//                      } else if (edge == RectangleEdge.TOP) {
//                          mark = new Line2D.Double(xx, cursor - ol,
//                                  xx, cursor + il);
//                      } else if (edge == RectangleEdge.BOTTOM) {
//                          mark = new Line2D.Double(xx, cursor + ol,
//                                  xx, cursor - il);
//                      }
//                      g2.draw(mark);
//                  }
//              }
//
//              // need to work out the space used by the tick labels...
//              // so we can update the cursor...
//              double used = 0.0;
//              if (isTickLabelsVisible()) {
//                  if (edge == RectangleEdge.LEFT) {
//                      used += findMaximumTickLabelWidth(ticks, g2,
//                              plotArea, isVerticalTickLabels());
//                      state.cursorLeft(used);
//                  } else if (edge == RectangleEdge.RIGHT) {
//                      used = findMaximumTickLabelWidth(ticks, g2,
//                              plotArea, isVerticalTickLabels());
//                      state.cursorRight(used);
//                  } else if (edge == RectangleEdge.TOP) {
//                      used = findMaximumTickLabelHeight(ticks, g2,
//                              plotArea, isVerticalTickLabels());
//                      state.cursorUp(used);
//                  } else if (edge == RectangleEdge.BOTTOM) {
//                      used = findMaximumTickLabelHeight(ticks, g2,
//                              plotArea, isVerticalTickLabels());
//                      state.cursorDown(used);
//                  }
//              }
//
//              return state;
//          }
//
//          @Override
//          protected void autoAdjustRange() {
//              // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//
//          }
//
//          @Override
//          public double java2DToValue(double arg0, Rectangle2D arg1,
//                  RectangleEdge arg2) {
//              // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//              return 0;
//          }
//
//          @Override
//          public double valueToJava2D(double arg0, Rectangle2D arg1,
//                  RectangleEdge arg2) {
//              // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//              return 0;
//          }
//
//          @Override
//          public void configure() {
//              // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//
//          }
//
//          @Override
//          public AxisState draw(Graphics2D arg0, double arg1,
//                  Rectangle2D arg2, Rectangle2D arg3,
//                  RectangleEdge arg4, PlotRenderingInfo arg5) {
//              // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//              return null;
//          }
//
//          @Override
//          public List refreshTicks(Graphics2D arg0, AxisState arg1,
//                  Rectangle2D arg2, RectangleEdge arg3) {
//              // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//              return null;
//          }
//      };
//
//      plot.setRangeAxis(axis);

        return chart;
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final BarChartDemo demo = new BarChartDemo("Bar Chart Demo");
        demo.pack();
        demo.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to remove the last value by:

```
NumberAxis rangeAxis = new NumberAxis() {

   @Override
   protected AxisState drawTickMarksAndLabels(Graphics2D g2,
       double cursor, Rectangle2D plotArea, Rectangle2D dataArea,
       RectangleEdge edge) {
           // CHANGES
}

plot.setRangeAxis(rangeAxis);
```